# Show hidden HTML element on click with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pure CSS modal named `.popup-container` by default is set to `display: none;` and I'm also using `blockUI` plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

The code I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.wait-me').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({  message: '<h1>Loading...</h1>', css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .9,
            color: '#fff' 
        }
    }); 

    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
});
```

The modal code:

```
.popup-container {
    background: #282828;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 400;
    display: none;

}

.popup-container:target {
        display: block;
}
```

I need to make my modal visible after 2,5 sec after I call `blockUI` function. First shows "Loading..." and after that I need to show my modal.

Now I call my modal like this:

```
<a href="#modal" class="wait-me">show modal after 2.5 sec</a>
```

Comment: Why not create a class `.wait-me` to replace all those `#wait-me-a, #wait-me-b, #wait-me-c, #wait-me-d, #wait-me-e, #wait-me-f` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(myBlock).ajaxStop(myUnblock);

var doBlock = false;
function myBlock() {
    doBlock = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (doBlock)
            $.blockUI({allYourSettingsDefined});
    }, 2000);
}

function myUnblock() {
    doBlock = false;
    $.unblockUI();
}
```

Comment: How to use your code? I cant see the click function and where is the .wait-me & .popup-container classes?